# Nano S Ethereum Public Key and Chain Code

Tags: public-key, ledger-nano-s

I'm trying to figure out how to get this repository (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ledgerhq/hw-app-eth) to interact with the Nano S ledger, the hardware wallet.

I can't figure out what tools or technologies I need to call methods like:

```
import Eth from "@ledgerhq/hw-app-eth";
const eth = new Eth(transport)

eth.getAddress("44'/60'/0'/0/0").then(o => o.address)
```

So I can get a public key and chain code from the hardware wallet.

Comment: Have you checked out their repo? https://github.com/LedgerHQ/ledgerjs

Comment: Yeah. I'm looking at it right now. I have to setup a "communication layer" with the device. But I'm currently not sure how to use the options they have on the repository.